# Polynomial regression exploding gradients and underfitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I wanted to code my implementation of polynomial regression, but my model's gradients either exploded or my model didn't fit the data well enough.

For testing purposes, my dataset is just the function `x^2` and my model is a second-degree polynomial `ax^2 + bx + c`. I trained it for 50 epochs using batch gradient descent.

I noticed that the model explodes with the learning rate `>=0.001` and underfits with a learning rate `<=0.0001`

To visualize the model, at the end of each epoch, I plot the model's predictions with the labels. So, in the ideal case, these lines should be indistinguishable.

**The orange line is the labels and the blue one is the model's predictions.*

**Here is the model exploding:***
[image]

[image]

**And here it underfits:***
[image]

One interesting thing is, that even though the model's predictions are way too big, the line still resembles the correct polynomial. And the picture where the predictions go into negatives is also correct, but just flipped/mirrored.

I made the code in python. This is my `main.py`:

```python
from decimal import Decimal

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, draw, pause, clf

from model import PolynomialRegression


POLYNOMIAL_FUNCTION = [0, 1, 2]
LEARNING_RATE = Decimal(0.0001)

DATASET = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
LABELSET = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 32, 64, 128]

EPOCHS = 50


model = PolynomialRegression(POLYNOMIAL_FUNCTION, LEARNING_RATE)


for _ in range(EPOCHS):
    for data, label in zip(DATASET, LABELSET):
        # train the model
        model.train(data, label)

    # update the model
    model.update()

    # predict the dataset
    predictions = [model.predict(data) for data in DATASET]

    # plot predictions and labels
    plot(predictions)
    plot(LABELSET)

    draw()
    pause(0.1)
    clf()

    print(model.parameters)

    # erase the stored gradients
    model.clear_grad()
```

And this is my `model.py`:

```python
from decimal import Decimal


class PolynomialRegression:
    """
    Polynomial regression model.
    """

    def __init__(self, polynomial_function: list, learning_rate: Decimal) -> None:
        # the structure of the polynomial function (the exponents)
        self.polynomial_function = polynomial_function

        # parameters of the model set to be 1
        self.parameters = [Decimal(1)] * len(polynomial_function)

        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        # stored gradients to update the model
        self.gradients = []
    
    def predict(self, x: Decimal) -> Decimal:
        """
        Make a prediction based on the input.

        Args:
            x (Decimal): Input to the model.

        Returns:
            Decimal: A prediction.
        """

        y = Decimal(0)

        # go through each parameter and exponent
        for param, exponent in zip(self.parameters, self.polynomial_function):
            # compute a term and add it to the final output
            y += param * (x ** exponent)
        
        return y
    
    def train(self, x: Decimal, y: Decimal) -> Decimal:
        """
        Compute a gradient from a given input and target output.

        Args:
            x (Decimal): Input for the model.
            y (Decimal): Target/Desired output.
        
        Returns:
            Decimal: An MSE loss.
        """

        prediction = self.predict(x)

        error = prediction - y
        loss = error ** 2

        gradient = []

        # go through each parameter and exponent
        for param, exponent in zip(self.parameters, self.polynomial_function):
            # compute the gradient for a single parameter
            param_gradient = error * (x ** exponent) * self.learning_rate
            
            # add the parameter gradient to the gradient list
            gradient.append(param_gradient)

        # add the gradient to a list
        self.gradients.append(gradient)

        return loss
    

    def __sum_gradients(self) -> Decimal:
        """
        Return a sum of gradients along the 0 axis.
        (equivalent of numpy.sum(x, axis=0))

        Returns:
            list: List of summed Decimals.
        """

        result = [Decimal(0)] * len(self.parameters)

        # iterate through the y axis
        for gradient in self.gradients:
            # iterate through the x axis
            for i, param_gradient in enumerate(gradient):
                result[i] += param_gradient
        
        return result

    def update(self) -> None:
        """
        Update the model's parameters based on the stored gradients.
        """

        summed_gradients = self.__sum_gradients()

        # fraction used to calculate the average for every gradient
        averaging_fraction = Decimal(1) / len(self.gradients)

        for param_index, grad in enumerate(summed_gradients):
            self.parameters[param_index] -= averaging_fraction * grad
        
    def clear_grad(self) -> None:
        """
        Clear/Reset the stored gradients.
        """

        self.gradients = []
```

I think the problem lies somewhere in my gradient descent calculations, but it may also be something unexpected and silly.

Answer (score 0):

First your dataset consists of only 8 datapoints. This is to few data to generalize a model, which means that you are probably overfitting.

The second thing I see, is that you do not normalize the x data. The model is not very complex so I guess it doesn't really matter in that context. But if you had a more complex model with n features and one feature is very small and one is very big, the feature with the bigger values would influence the result much more than the smaller one. Which might result in a bad performing model.

But your last plot doesn't look like it's underfitting to me. You have to realize that a ML model will always have an error. In my opinion for 8 datapoints, a model with only one layer and 50 epochs that looks fine. You probably could improve the results by learning longer, but that would mean to overfit the model even more. But to be honest if your goal is to emulate a mathematical function with ML this should be okay. You could also add a new layer.

The fact that your lr has to be that small to not fuck up the results tells me that you are correct, there is something wrong with the gradient descent you might want to look into this behavior.

An easy way to evaluate this is to build your model in pytorch and then use your optimizer to update the weights. If you get the same problem, it was your gradient descent, if not the problem lies somewhere else. But I strongly believe it is your gradient descent. Maybe debug into this function and look at the actual values you are subtracting.